# How does ToString on an anonymous type work?

Tags: c#, .net, tostring, anonymous-types

I was messing with anonymous types, and I accidentally outputted it onto the console. It looked basically how I defined it.

Here's a short program that reproduces it:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Integer = 2;
        DateTime DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(new { Test = 0, Integer, s = DateTime });
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Now, the output is:

```
{ Test = 0, Integer = 2, s = 28/05/2013 15:07:19 }
```

I tried using dotPeek to get into the assembly to find out why, but it was no help.<sup>[1]</sup> Here's the dotPeek'd code:

```
// Type: Program
// Assembly: MyProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// Assembly location: Not telling you! :P
using System;
internal class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine((object) new
    {
      Test = 0,
      Integer = 2,
      s = DateTime.Now
    });
    Console.ReadKey(true);
  }
}
```

So not much different, at all.

So how does it work? How does it output it like that?

Notes:

<sup>[1]</sup>: I forgot to turn on "Show compiler-generated code", that's the reason I didn't get how it works.

Comment: By design? What's the actual question/problem here?

Comment: I'm wondering how it works!

Comment: Maybe ToString uses reflection.. to print each key value pair.

Comment: @LewsTherin I'm thinking that would be excessive, but it is possible!

Comment: Disassemble the .Net Assembly where anonymous types reside; the ToString method must be overloaded and invoking the ToString of each property. I usually use ILSpy

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Shrugs.. no idea. But not that excessive methinks

Comment: Well, anonymous types are _actual_ types compiled on-the-fly. I see no reason why the .NET developers didn't also have them implement a full `ToString` override which takes into account each member of the anonymous type.

Comment: Shall we quote the C# Language Specification in our answers?

Comment: @LuisFilipe I mentioned I used dotPeek, and posted the output from dotPeek.

Comment: @Jeppe that would be a challenge: the specification does not define any behavior for `ToString` on anonymous types

Comment: @MarcGravell You're right, I just found out because I wanted to quote from it in an answer. So my comment was irrelevant. I will upvote your answer below because you mention this!

Comment: Downvoter, I've realized you're probably long-gone, but if you aren't: care to explain why? And no, it isn't obvious. 10 people would disagree with you on that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just to add some code to HuorSwords answer, compiler will *generate* `ToString` method for your example, as given below:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.Append("{ Test = ");
    stringBuilder.Append((object) this.<Test>__Field);
    stringBuilder.Append(", Integer = ");
    stringBuilder.Append((object) this.<Integer>__Field);
    stringBuilder.Append(", s = ");
    stringBuilder.Append((object) this.<s>__Field);
    stringBuilder.Append(" }");
    return ((object) stringBuilder).ToString();
}
```

It would be performance inefficient to use reflection here, when you have all required metadata at compile time.

Decompiled using **dotPeek**, this version may vary depending on used decompiler.

Note: as you also decompiled with dotPeek, try to look at *Root Namespace*. There you will find something similar to:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("\\{ Test = {Test}, Integer = {Integer}, s = {s} }", Type = "<Anonymous Type>")]
internal sealed class <>__AnonymousType0<<Test>
```

This is an example  of what the compiled generates, when you define anonymous objects.

Comment: The reason I missed it is because I forgot to turn on "Show compiler generated code". Thanks though, +1!

Answer (score 20):

With anonymous objects...

> The compiler generates an internal sealed class that models the
>   anonymous type. The anonymous type is immutable; all the properties
>   are read only. That class contains overrides of Equals() and
>   GetHashCode() that implement value semantics. In addition, the
>   compiler generates an override of ToString() that displays the value
>   of each of the public properties.

Source : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee957397.aspx)

Please, check ***@Ilya Ivanov*** answer to see some code about this subject.

Comment: The source seems to be gone. This is the latest working snapshot in WayBack Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140605054448/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee957397.aspx

Also, I can still find the contents here, in PDF: http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/4/B/54B83DFE-D7AA-4155-9687-B0CF58FF65D7/tuples-anon-types-concrete.pdf

Answer (score 15):

Anonymous types are still fully defined types... simply: the compiler generates them entirely itself, and you never see the name / implementation (just: it matches the initializer you use in your code).

Actually, the `ToString` is **not mentioned** in regard to anonymous types in the specification (*section 7.6.10.6*); it is only *required* that `Equals` and `GetHashCode` work in terms of the properties. The example in the specification ("declares an anonymous type of the form") does ***not*** include a `ToString` override.

The MS compiler adds a property-based implementation of `ToString` *as a courtesy* - but also perhaps because the *default* `ToString` is the type name, which would by itself be meaningless (it is, after all, anonymous - the type name is pretty horrible to read, and includes generics syntax). Frankly, it would be a good idea to only use this for debugging purposes.