# Why does compiler generate different classes for anonymous types if the order of fields is different

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

I've considered 2 cases:

```
var a = new { a = 5 };
var b = new { a = 6 };
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType() == b.GetType()); // True
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/F8QwHY

and:

```
var a = new { a = 5, b = 7 };
var b = new { b = 7, a = 6 };
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType() == b.GetType()); // False
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/hDTcxX

The question is why does order of fields actually matter?

Is there any reason for this or it's just simply because it is (such is the design).

If the reason is just that anonymus types are not supposed to be used this way and you are not supposed to appeal to `GetType`, then why does compiler re-use a single class in first case and not just generate a new class for each anonymus type declaration?

Comment: What means _"anonymus types are not supposed to be used this way "_? What way? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Eric Lippert blogged about this exact thing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/30/anonymous-types-unify-within-an-assembly-part-two.aspx

Comment: One slightly mundane reason is that the `ToString()` method for anonymous classes honors the order in which the properties are declared, so obviously separate classes are needed to take that into account.

Comment: Kinda-related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794275/How-does-ToString-on-an-anonymous-type-work

Comment: Is this an *actual* programming problem you are facing?

Comment: @user414076, problems can be solved pro-actively, not only reactively. I'm just interested why does compiler work this way. You'll find a lot of somewhat similar questions on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the reason for the design decision was `ToString`. An anonymous type returns a different `string` accoding to the order. Read [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/30/anonymous-types-unify-within-an-assembly-part-two.aspx).

```
{ a = 5, b = 7 }
{ b = 7, a = 6 }
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/6VOnF3)

Comment: I'd guess that the `GetHashCode` implementation also depends on the order.

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, it does. However,  both depend on each other. So different `ToString` with same hashcode or same hashcode on different `ToString` would have been a pitfall.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Why would same hashcode but different `ToString` have been a pitfall?  Having `Equals` methods report instances of different types as equal would be a pitfall, but occasional hash-code collisions between unequal objects are reasonably expected.

Answer (score 7):

C# language specification, section 7.6.10.6, requires the sequence of properties to be the same in order for the anonymous types to be considered identical:

> Within the same program, two anonymous object initializers that specify a sequence of properties of the same names and compile-time types in the same order will produce instances of the same anonymous type.

In your second example, the first anonymous class has the sequence of properties `{a, b}`, while the second anonymous class has the sequence `{b, a}`. These sequences are not considered to be the same.

Comment: Thank you, although your answer has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Well, this answer just raises the question of why the specification is written that way. Eric Lippert answers [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/30/anonymous-types-unify-within-an-assembly-part-two.aspx).

Comment: @Artur Udod: I wouldn't go that far.

Comment: @Jason, yes, thank you and Oded for this article. Would have accepted if that was an asnwer.

Comment: @ArturUdod I am confused as to how this doesn't relate to your question. You asked why the order matters, he answered. I read your question, and I read his answer, it all made sense to me.

Comment: @JeremyK It's correct, but "the spec says so" is usually not a very satisfying explanation.

Comment: So, C# works this way, because that's written in the C# spec? okay, let's go step further: why is C# spec written that way.

Comment: @Rawling true, but to say it had nothing to do with his question isn't an accurate statement :) He was being a bit rude imo.

Comment: @ArturUdod "The question is why does order of fields actually matter?

Is there any reason for this or it's just simply because it is (such is the design)." Your question was generic enough for a generic answer. You wanted to know if it was this way because it was designed this way. his answer straight out said yes, this is how the language was designed.

Comment: @JeremyK, if I was, I apologise, that was not intentionally. I'm not a native english-speaker, so my phrases are basicaly crude and straightforward.

Comment: Fair enough :) I understand the desire for more information. Just thought he did provide the answer to what was asked. /Cheers

Comment: @ArturUdod "... has nothing to do with my question." Why? Didn't you ask "why does order of fields actually matter?" The answer is "because the spec says so". If you wanted to know why the spec was written that way, you should have asked that explicitly. (Then I probably wouldn't answer, because all questions about "why the spec has been written this or that way" are addressed mostly to Eric Lippert :-)

Comment: @JeremyK, I was asking if there's a specific reason for this, and there actually is: GetHashCode & ToString() implementations.

Comment: `because the spec says so` is a genuine answer to all questions that start with `why does compiler ...`

Comment: @ArturUdod That's not universally true: sometimes, the spec gives compilers some freedom about what they can do; sometimes, spec does not say anything about a particular problem; sometimes, compilers have bugs. Anyway, if you wanted to discuss the reasons behind the spec being written one way or the other, you should have asked about the spec, not about a program behavior.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, okay, I got your point. Sorry if I was offensive. Thank you for your answer, and btw I did give you an upvote, just wanted to go a little bit deeper.

Answer (score 4):

You lead on to what I'm guessing the reason is: the types are anonymous so depending on  `GetType()` to return reliable results is a terrible idea.

As for why the compiler re-uses a type if the order matches, I'm guessing it's simply to save time and space. When you take order into account, it's far easier to cache generated classes during compilation and then re-use them when needed.

Comment: It also has to do with them having proper ToString representations.