# Linq query printing curly braces '{' in result

Tags: linq, curly-braces

I need to query multiple columns using Linq query and as far as I know I need to use the Curly braces '{}'

I wrote the following query but for some strange reason its printing the opening and closing braces '{}' that's in the statement.

```
var q = db.table1.Where(n => n.user== USER).Select(n => new { n.Name, n.LastName }); 
            ViewBag.test = q;
```

In My View

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.test)
{
    @item
}
```

Output:

```
{ Name = john, LastName=Smith}
{ Name = Mike, LastName=mojie}
```

Why is it printing the curly braces?!

Answer (score 4):

Because that's the default implementation of [`ToString` for an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16794275/497356).

You could try:

```
@(item.Name + " " + item.LastName)
```

Comment: I tried it and it return this error: 
`'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'`

Comment: @ceci: I think that's because `ViewBag` is dynamic. If you use `dynamic` instead of `var` it may work. You could also try actually declaring a type and using that instead of an anonymous type.